# Is Django 4 async faster then sync queries

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to do an exercise to evaluate the value of upgrading to Django 4 and changing some of the queryset to async.

To try and assess performance, I've created a couple of views to assess sync vs async and at present I can't see any performance improvement when communicating with the database.

Firstly, I intentionally created two inefficient views where the db is supposed to be hit hard:

**Sync**

```py
def some_validation(post):
    """Check that number of tags > 5"""
    return post.tags.count() > 5


@api_view(["GET"])
def posts_with_tags(request):
    start_time = time.monotonic()
    posts = []
    for post in Post.objects.all():
        tags = []
        for tag in post.tags.all():
            tags.append(tag.name)
        post_data = {
            "id": post.id,
            "title": post.title,
            "content": post.content,
            "tags": tags,
            "validation_passed": some_validation(post),
        }
        posts.append(post_data)
    end_time = time.monotonic()
    time_elapsed = end_time - start_time
    return Response(
        {
            "posts": posts,
            "time_elapsed": time_elapsed,
            "num_queries": len(connection.queries),
        }
    )
```

**Async**

```py
async def some_validation_async(post):
    """Check that number of tags > 5"""
    return await post.tags.acount() > 5


@api_view(["GET"])
async def posts_with_tags_async(request):
    start_time = time.monotonic()

    post_data = []

    async for post in Post.objects.all():
        post_tags = []
        async for tag in post.tags.all():
            post_tags.append(tag.name)

        validation_res = await some_validation_async(post)

        post_data.append(
            {
                "id": post.id,
                "title": post.title,
                "content": post.content,
                "tags": post_tags,
                "validation_passed": validation_res,
            }
        )

    end_time = time.monotonic()
    time_elapsed = end_time - start_time

    return Response(
        {
            "posts": post_data,
            "time_elapsed": time_elapsed,
            "num_queries": len(connection.queries),
        }
    )
```

Similarly, I have created views to write and delete data. In all cases, I'm not seeing a performance improvement when interacting with querysets asynchronously.

Would someone have an idea as to what I might be missing as I would have assumed that the async. querysets may have improved performance?

Comment: Async doesn't mean *faster*, it just means more efficient use of (CPU) processes across multiple requests.

Comment: So let's suppose the validation actually did something more than just counting and verifying the number is greater than 5, I suppose that would be a situation where async might be useful.